# Error when configure flutter web firebase. Error: Method not found: 'guardWebExceptions'. return internals.guardWebExceptions(

Tags: firebase, flutter

when i try to setup flutter website firebase i get a lot of errors. here's the error I have
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_web-2.6.9/lib/src/internals.dart:11:20: Error: Method not found: 'guardWebExceptions'.
return internals.guardWebExceptions(

```
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_storage_web-3.2.9/lib/src/utils/errors.dart:20:20: Error: Method not found: 'guardWebExceptions'.
return internals.guardWebExceptions(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.5.0/lib/src/method_channel/method_channel_firestore.dart:112:15: Error: Member not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace' .
Error.throwWithStackTrace(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

this is main.dart code

```
import 'package:admin_dashboard/login_page.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

[here my pubspec.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOYy3.png)`

Answer (score 1):

This is due to out dated version.

Try to find the flutter SDK version.

If the SDK version is 2.10.0-0.3, update the version using the following command,

> flutter upgrade

To know about the out dated packages run,

> flutter pub outdated

To update the out dated packages run,

> flutter pub upgrade --major-versions

Then run your flutter project.

I hope these commands might help you.